# Is there comprehensive list of activation functions and their applications for a Neural Network?

Tags: neural-network, activation-function

I am aware of common activation functions like sigmoid, tanh,ReLu, Leaky ReLu. Even heard about a function called Swish. Now is there any detailed information on other activations functions and some applications/comparative study on what functions performed better on what scenarios/dataset/problems ?

Comment: this has already been asked: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115258/comprehensive-list-of-activation-functions-in-neural-networks-with-pros-cons

Comment: also see: https://www.upgrad.com/blog/types-of-activation-function-in-neural-networks/, https://towardsdatascience.com/activation-functions-neural-networks-1cbd9f8d91d6, https://machinelearningmastery.com/choose-an-activation-function-for-deep-learning/

Comment: The previous links discuss the usual activation functions, but the point is that one can use a custom activation function if it suits the needs of the problem, so an exhaustive list is impossible

Comment: Not really answering your question, but most of the people I work with (working on **Computer Vision**) seem to agree on the fact that activation functions do not make a big difference and it is mostly the architecture that will determine the results of your network. We tend to use ReLU functions everywhere without even thinking if other functions would be a better match.

Comment: thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Shortly after the success of ReLU was demonstrated, there was a flood of research papers describing the performance of different exotic activations. There are probably hundreds of different activation functions that have been published, many of which just never caught on. You can literally use any univariate function as an activation, so the space of "possible" acitvation functions is infinite.

A better question is "where can I find a comprehensive list of *useful* activation functions?" I think an easy definition for useful is "I can actually experiment with this easily in a model I want to build right now," in which case the easy solution is to just check the docs of your framework of choice. For example, here are the activation functions that come out of the box with pytorch:

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#non-linear-activations-weighted-sum-nonlinearity

I count 29 activation functions there. Is it "comprehensive" with respect to published research? No probably not. But if someone published an activation function five years ago or whatever and it still hasn't made its way into pytroch, I'd argue that you probably don't need to be worried about its absence.

If you want to know how these different activation functions perform, your best bet is to dig up the papers that introduced them. They will include benchmarks and describe what motivated the shape of the activation function and what problem domains the authors expect it to work well on. You could even find examples of their usage via paperswithcode, e.g.: https://paperswithcode.com/method/relu

Comment: thanks for your explanation!

Comment: If you found that explanation helpful, you should consider "accepting" the answer. Welcome to stackexchange :)